Disagreement of additive structures on a R-groupoid
Let $M$ be a monoid $(M, \cdot)$ and $(M, \cdot , +)$ and $(M, \cdot, \oplus)$ be two (not necessarily isomorphic) rings. I defined two interesting functions $[x] = x \oplus (-x)$ and $\langle x \rangle = x + (\ominus x)$. I was wondering if $[x] = 0$, then does $\langle x \rangle = 0$?
Or… are all additive structures on a monoid isomorphic?

Rings are not determined solely by their multiplicative structure. Let's rewrite your equation by moving the other term to the right. If $x = \ominus - x$, does $x = -\ominus x$ hold? Well, the assumption implies then $- \ominus x = - \ominus \ominus - x = x$.

Thank you. Yes, additionally it seems that if a monoid is the multiplicative structure of a ring, then all monoids isomorphic to it are also multiplicative structures of a ring, as $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x) + \varphi(y))$ forms an additive structure where $\varphi$ is of course the monoid isomorphism between the multiplicative structures and $+$ an addition operation on the ring.

You're welcome. If something is isomorphic, it is indistinguishable in that context, so what you're saying makes sense. An alternative notation for what you wrote is $\phi^*(+)$, the pullback of the binary operator $+$. The pullback of a map $\phi$ can pull back a structure when $\phi$ is an isomorphism (and so can the pushforward).
